# Output of UNION query

Tags: union

## `UNION`

Suppose 2 `SELECT` queries are joined by `UNION`. Can I get output if the 2nd `SELECT` query has 0 rows and 1st `SELECT` query returned some rows?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will have output even if only 1 of the `SELECT` query has results.

Though by default, you cannot determine if the result was from the 1st or 2nd `SELECT` query, you can include an additional column in each query to determine where in those `SELECT` query the result came from. See this [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ff6b8/2639)

Comment: +1 but the two `SELECT` are not separate statements. The whole `SELECT ... UNION SELECT ... ;` is a single statement. I think the technical term for each part of the UNION is *"query term"*.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ, thanks, i'll take note of that.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=54dd5d641ee6a9ef0f3c9a7f3e62fe0b) and play around with the `WHERE` clauses!